# Extracting friends' E-Mail addresses from Facebook (Skype?)

Tags: facebook, skype

I am currently in the process of migrating away from Facebook (privacy concerns, mostly). For obvious reasons, I want to save away the email addresses from my friends' profile pages. However, this turned out to be a rather hard task, because the Facebook API doesn't let you access any mail addresses.

However, I just tried the automatic contact import feature of Skype, and it seems to be able to retrieve the email addresses of my friends from Facebook.

Does anyone know how it's done so I could replicate it?

Answer (score 2):

You can NOT do it via API, you know Skype and yahoo have the email importer because they work together with facebook.

If you need to get all your friends email on a file, use the Yahoo email importer then export your contacts as a csv or txt file.